# scrabing using requests in python

Tags: python, automation, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to get some info from this `API` site :

https://billing.te.eg/api/Account/Inquiry

(originial here : https://billing.te.eg/ar-eg) , it like you inquiry with code `(ex:055)` and number `(ex:3020100)` and it return bill , I try to make it in python with requests but I always fail , I found this code `written` in `vba` and I try it in `Excel` and yeh it work , the code is

Sub FetchData()
Const Url$ = "https://billing.te.eg/api/Account/Inquiry"
Dim S$, elem As Object, payload As Variant
Dim phone$, areaCode$, counter&

```
counter = 1
areaCode = "055"        'put areacode here
phone = "3020105"     'put phone number here

payload = "AreaCode=" & areaCode & "&PhoneNumber=" & phone & "&PinCode=&InquiryBy=telephone&AccountNo="

Do
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://billing.te.eg/en-US"
        .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send payload
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "TotalAmount"":(.*?),"
        Set elem = .Execute(S)
        If elem.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox elem(0).SubMatches(0)
            Exit Do
        End If
    End With

    counter = counter + 1
    If counter = 3 Then Exit Do
Loop
```

End Sub

can any one help me to make this code `runnable` on `python` with request or any other library , this is what I try with `python` but didn't work :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://billing.te.eg/api/Account/Inquiry"
payload = {'AreaCode': '055', 'PhoneNumber': '3020105', 'PinCode': '', 'InquiryBy': 'telephone', 'AccountNo': ''}
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36',
'Referer': 'https://billing.te.eg/ar-eg',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
request = requests.post(url,verify = False, headers=headers, data=payload)  
cont = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(cont, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Comment: Can you check if the website url is working? Because to me it shows Contact Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example how to load the JSON data using Python:

```
import json
import requests


url = "https://billing.te.eg/api/Account/Inquiry"

data = {
    "AreaCode": "055",         # <-- change this
    "PhoneNumber": "3020100",  # <-- change this
    "PinCode": "",
    "InquiryBy": "telephone",
    "AccountNo": "",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    # load cookies
    s.get("https://billing.te.eg/ar-eg", verify=False)
    resp = s.post(url, data=data, verify=False).json()

    # pretty print the returned data:
    print(json.dumps(resp, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "Account": {
        "InquiryByNewAndPhoneNotChanged": false,
        "InquiryByOldAndPhoneChanged": false,
        "UnPaidInvoices": [
            {
                "ID": "A2003249299202007",
                "AccountNo": "A2003249299",
                "AreaCode": "055",
                "PhoneNumber": "03020100",
                "Frequency": 0,
                "BillDateClient": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 1,
                    "Month": 6,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "CategoryID": 78,
                "InquiryDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "SubscribtionStart": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 1,
                    "Month": 6,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "SubscribtionEnd": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 30,
                    "Month": 8,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "ConsumptionStart": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 1,
                    "Month": 3,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "ConsumptionEnd": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 30,
                    "Month": 5,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "TotalAmount": 80.1,
                "InvoiceDetails": null,
                "PaymentDateClient": null,
                "PaymentDate": null,
                "PenaltyDate": "2021-04-15T00:00:00",
                "PaymentGateNameAr": "",
                "PaymentGateNameEn": null,
                "PaymentGateName": "",
                "PaymentCollectionType": {
                    "ID": -1,
                    "NameAr": "",
                    "NameEn": "",
                    "Name": ""
                },
                "PFlag": "0",
                "Status": 0,
                "BeingPaidStatus": 0,
                "PreviousUnPaidInvoices": null
            }
        ],
        "HasPreviousUnPaidInvoice": true,
        "InquiryTelephoneNumber": null,
        "InquiryAreaCode": "055",
        "InquiryPhoneNumber": "03020100",
        "HasLoyalty": false,
        "RechargeSign": "",
        "BalanceDetailsSign": "058152CDA2088BCBAE02D0851B507337",
        "CategoryIDClient": "54DEFC7260353AFB1D41086B607385F0",
        "Status": 4,
        "Customer": {
            "AreaCode": "055",
            "PhoneNumber": "03020100",
            "Account": "A2003249299",
            "CategoryName": "WE \u0623\u0631\u0636\u064a",
            "HasDeposit": true,
            "DepositValue": 10.12,
            "Frequency": 1,
            "CategoryIdValue": "54DEFC7260353AFB1D41086B607385F0",
            "HasMultibleTelephones": false,
            "AssociatedTelephonesFormatted": "05503020100",
            "AllowToRecharge": false,
            "IsBusiness": false,
            "AllowForRfpService": false,
            "PinCodeReference": "",
            "AssociatedTelephones": "05503020100",
            "SignValue": "D7EE0B774BF213839D4E0F30AC28A40A"
        },
        "Invoices": [
            {
                "ID": "A2003249299202007",
                "AccountNo": "A2003249299",
                "AreaCode": "055",
                "PhoneNumber": "03020100",
                "Frequency": 0,
                "BillDateClient": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 1,
                    "Month": 6,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "CategoryID": 78,
                "InquiryDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "SubscribtionStart": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 1,
                    "Month": 6,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "SubscribtionEnd": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 30,
                    "Month": 8,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "ConsumptionStart": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 1,
                    "Month": 3,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "ConsumptionEnd": {
                    "Sec": 0,
                    "Min": 0,
                    "Hour": 0,
                    "Day": 30,
                    "Month": 5,
                    "Year": 2020
                },
                "TotalAmount": 80.1,
                "InvoiceDetails": null,
                "PaymentDateClient": null,
                "PaymentDate": null,
                "PenaltyDate": "2021-04-15T00:00:00",
                "PaymentGateNameAr": "",
                "PaymentGateNameEn": null,
                "PaymentGateName": "",
                "PaymentCollectionType": {
                    "ID": -1,
                    "NameAr": "",
                    "NameEn": "",
                    "Name": ""
                },
                "PFlag": "0",
                "Status": 0,
                "BeingPaidStatus": 0,
                "PreviousUnPaidInvoices": null
            }
        ],
        "PreviousUnPaidInvoices": null
    },
    "UnPaidInvoices": "AD8EDAFCCC849D5D8F872C1970F05887z1rkc0R2AUdZFMoHuCx7uhsYBH+2mP6GKIWJwAjWyG245pCPEp4jraLnHZ9CVmd4gBSLcgkZM5M/VYL6LOuMW1Osqstt5NbPiymDyXlqPmJ28ks6EyOlf8W/crq79625",
    "InfoMessage": null
}
```

Comment: can i do the same thing for this site (https://pay.jumia.com.eg/services/internet-bills/we-dsl) , please do it in detais and if there is any detailed refrence for learn requesets with sites that need information to path and how i got them from google chrome

Answer (score 0):

can i do the same thing for this site (pay.jumia.com.eg/services/internet-bills/we-dsl) , please do it in detais and if there is any detailed refrence for learn requesets with sites that need information to path and how i got them from google chrome